# WIndows - ImageMagick convert font to image

Tags: windows, imagemagick, label, imagemagick-convert

I use ImageMagick 7 to generate a font book by using this command:

```
for /R "G:\Fonts" %%a in ("*.?tf") do (
  "D:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.2-Q16\convert.exe" -antialias -pointsize 80 -font "%%a" label:@G:\Fonts\_\label.txt "G:\Fonts\_\__blank.jpg" "G:\Fonts\_\%%~na.jpg"
)
```

I have a text file called label.txt which contains accented characters in UTF-8, and a blank image to write on it.

The result is pretty odd: 2 images are generated
- one with the path instead of the content text
- one blank

[Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj9iN.jpg)

Any idea?

Regards

Comment: I found my two answers :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I found.

First I've removed the blank image.
Second I've noticed my **label.txt** file had disappeared...

Final code:

```
for /R "G:\Fonts" %%a in ("*.?tf") do (
  "D:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.2-Q16\convert.exe"   -antialias -pointsize 80 -font "%%a"  label:@G:\Fonts\_\label.txt "G:\Fonts\_\%%~na.jpg"
)
```